# Communicate two azure tenants

Tags: azure, entra-id, azure-networking

I need to communicate two tenants azures.

The first one contains a bus service. The second contains Dynamics crm.

How can I do this knowing that the first tenant does not allow external access via the internet?

While searching in the internet, they talked about several solutions: Azure expressRoute. virtual network peering. VNet-to-VNet:

I don't really understand the differences, advantages and disadvantages between the different solutions.

Do you have any solutions to propose to me?

Comment: I've found the Azure Private Link feature. It might be used to create connection between endpoints without exposure to a public internet. Followign preview might be helpful: https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/what-is-azure-private-link-preview

Answer (score 0):

Check cross-tenant Vnet peering:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/cross-aad-vnet-peering/